# Reset form button React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a form with a reset button in order to clear all fields, so I'm building a Class Component. I don't like the idea of using `setState` in each field. Do you know any better way to clear this form?

Simplified code example:

```
class Registration extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state= {}

}
render() {
  return (
    <View >
      <View >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ styles.button }}
          onPress={ } >
          <Text style={{ style.text }} >RESET</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <ScrollView>
          <View  >
            <TextInput 
              ref={this.textInput}
              style={{ styles.input }}
              placeholder='Name'
              onChangeText={(text) => { }}
            />
          </View>
          <View >
            <TextInput 
              style={{ styles.input}}
              onChangeText={(text) => { }}
              placeholder='Username'
            />
          </View>
          <View >
            <TextInput 
              style={{ styles.input}}
              onChangeText={(text) => { }}
              placeholder='password'
            />
          </View>
          <View >
            <TextInput 
              style={{ styles.input}}
              onChangeText={(text) => { }}
              placeholder='email'
            />
          </View>
          .
          .
          .
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a better way than to use a state variable for each field of the form. Furthermore, to clear the form data you wouldn't need to clear each field individually. You could do something like this ```this.setState({ userName: "", password: "", email: "" })```

Maybe you could explain why you don't want to use a state variable for each field if you want a different solution ?

Comment: it is just that the form has at least 12 fields and I thought it would be repetitive maybe someone knows a more optimal way